# Does JIT convert the binary code of IL into binary machine code?

Tags: .net, clr

This is regarding .NET.

1. Code (high-level: c#,vb.net - human understandable) is compiled in VS and dll/exe is generated This is called IL (this is also more or less human understandable).
2. When we run this dll/exe for the first time on the machine, the CLR/JIT converts the IL to machine code (binary format: 0's and 1's - this is not human understandable). This machine code is saved in memory so next time the conversion is not required unless the system is restarted.
3. ILASM.exe can be used to convert the dll/exe (IL code) into machine code and ILDASM.exe is other opposite.

If the compiler generates exe/dll (IL) which is in binary format, then, what is purpose of the JIT? Since code is already in binary format... **Does it mean that the binary code of IL is converted into binary machine code by JIT?**

Please correct me on above statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Code (high-level: c#,vb.net - human understandable) is compiled in VS and dll/exe is generated This is called IL (this is also more or less human understandable).

You need to differentiate between the *binary* form of IL, and the *textual* form of IL - if you open up a compiled EXE or DLL file, you won't see text, so *that* isn't human readable... but the textual representation is a sort of "object oriented assembly language". The binary representation is "machine code for a CLI" - but that's not the *native* machine code of the computer you're running on.

> This machine code is saved in memory so next time the conversion is not required.

No, not as far as I'm aware - it's only retained in the *process*, in most cases. So if you start another process, it will JIT the code again.

> ILASM.exe can be used to convert the dll/exe (IL code) into machine code and ILDASM.exe is other opposite. Is this saved in memory also? What is file format?

No, that's not true. ILASM takes *source* IL (text) and assembles it into *binary* IL... it doesn't convert it into machine code. ILDASM does the reverse - it will convert a DLL or EXE into textual IL, that can be read.

> When would one make use of tool like ILASM?

I sometimes use ILDASM to look at the IL for a particular compiled binary (although I usually use Reflector). I use ILASM more rarely - usually after using ILDASM to get the text IL, then I've tweaked it in some interesting way. You could look at my [Unconstrained Melody](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) project for an example of this, where I tweak the IL to represent generic constraints which can't be represented in C#.

Comment: We write C#.NET code in Visual Studio and compile it. This generates EXE/DLL. Is'nt EXE/DLL an IL code?

Comment: @variable: Yes, but it's the *binary* representation of IL. I've expanded my answer a bit.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me how to generate textual representation?

Comment: @variable: Generate it from what? From a binary, you use ILDASM, as I say in my answer.

Comment: Ok, so you mean that when we compile using VS it will generate exe/dll which is nothing but a binary format IL code. To convert this to readable we have to use ILDASM.. ok..

Comment: If this is what you say, then what is the purpose of CLR/JIT. My undeerstanding is that the binary (machine code) format is created only when you run the exe for 1st time... Please correct me if wrong

Comment: The JIT is just part of the CLR. It converts binary IL into machine-native code as it's required. As far as I'm aware, it doesn't store that anywhere, other than in memory (although you can use ngen to compile it ahead of time, and that *does* store the results).